# Directory issues with joomla install, realized I was running as root

Tags: permissions, root, websites, joomla

Sorry if this is long: I'm running version 12.04, Apache web server and php 5

I am attempting to install joomla in var/www/, everything seemed to have went ok but as I was viewing my directory permissions via the joomla control panel I noticed that nothing was available for writing. After doing a little more research I found that the file permissions we right (644 and 755) but then I noticed that I extracted the folder as root.

I am assuming because I did this as root, instead of another users, it will not allow me to write to those folders unless it's 777 (which i've tested on a second install)

Is there a proper way or tutorial for creating a website with a different user that would allow proper directory permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You can change owners for the directory with the following

```
chown apacheuser joomladir -R
```

Just change the apacheuser and joomladir to the appropriate user and directory.

Edit:

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165183/apache-permissions-php-file-create-mkdir-fail) when I was researching another issue.  His answer is a lot more detailed than mine, and probably has some information that would be relevant to you.